# How to properly handle if a function exits without encoutering a return

Tags: c++

I have a function that search a vector and returns the item if it is found. But I want to know that best software appraoch to handle if it is not found.

I have created a function and could return -1 or something but that wouldn't match the return type.

```
koalaGraph::PVertex Koala::lookUpVertexbyName(const std::string&vertexName, const std::vector<koalaGraph::PVertex>& koalaVertices) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < koalaVertices.size(); i++) {

        if(koalaVertices[i]->info.name == vertexName) 
            return koalaVertices[i];
    }
}
```

If a situation is encountered where the item being searched for is not in the vector then program will exit.

Comment: could you not define an invalid `koalaGraph::PVertex` and return this? The calling code needs to check if it's invalid or not before deciding to use it

Comment: "How to handle errors" is really too broad for a simple Q&A.  There are three choices: 1.  Throw an exception.  2.  Actual result is returned in an argument passed by reference, and the function returns an error code (or success).  3.  Function returns actual result but you have a known value (like -1, or nullptr) which means "an error occured".  The appropriate style depends on a lot of things.

Comment: You should either return `optional<koalaGraph::PVertex>` or throw an exception if missing value is not expected or call `abort` if it would violate some constraint.

Comment: If `koalaVertices[i]` is a pointer, you could return `nullptr` or a pointer to some specially designated variable. Then you can compare the returned pointer with one of those.

Answer (score 9):

You can use [`std::optional`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional)

```
#include <optional>
std::optional<koalaGraph::PVertex> 
Koala::lookUpVertexbyName(const std::string&vertexName, 
                          const std::vector<koalaGraph::PVertex>& koalaVertices) {

    for (size_t i = 0; i < koalaVertices.size(); i++) {

        if(koalaVertices[i]->info.name == vertexName) 
            return koalaVertices[i];
    }
    return {};
}

int main()
{
    Koala k;
    //...
    auto maybeVertex = k.lookUpVertexByName("foo",vertices);
    if(maybeVertex)
        koalaGraph::PVertex&& vertex = *maybeVertex;
    //alternatively
    if(maybeVertex.has_value())
        //found
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You could use a `for`-loop and return a iterator.

```
std::vector<koalaGraph::PVertex>::const_iterator
Koala::lookUpVertexbyName(
        const std::string&vertexName, 
        const std::vector<koalaGraph::PVertex>& koalaVertices) 
{
    for(auto iter = koalaVertices.begin(); iter != koalaVertices.end(); ++iter) {
        if(koalaVertices[i]->info.name == vertexName) {
            return iter;
        }
    }
    return koalaVertices.end();
}
```

Further you check if you got `end` back. `end` indicates if the value was found or not.

```
auto iter = <fucntioncall> // lookUpVertexbyName
if (iter == <vector>.end() {
    // abort or do what ever you want
}
```

To use the value you have to dereference the iterator. DON'T derefence the `end`-iterator, it will lead you to neverland -> undefined behavior.

```
std::string test = *iter;
```

Comment: This is incorrect. He is comparing koalaVertices[i]->info.name to vertexName.

Comment: Dereferencing the end()-iterator is undefined behavior (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/end) so this approach does not work.

Comment: edited one more time, no the code is tested with gcc, clang and visual studio 2017

Comment: @skratchi.at thanks for your answer - why do you return a vector though?

Comment: I return an iterator. So to speak an element of the `std::vector`

Answer (score 2):

Why not use `std::find_if` instead of reinventing the wheel. See this [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/).

```
struct equal
{
    equal(const std::string& vertexName) : vertexName_(vertexName) { }
    bool operator()(const koalaGraph::PVertex& pVertex) const 
    {
        return  pVertex->info.name == vertexName_;
    } 

    private:
        std::string vertexName_;
};
```

And then:

`std::find_if(koalaVertices.begin(), koalaVertices.end(), eq(vertexName));`

Regarding handling the errors in function as it has already been stated there are multiple approaches that one can take. Returning an iterator instead of object(you will avoid copying this way too) is one of them. `end()` iterator would then indicate that the name was not found.

Answer (score 1):

There are three ways to exit a function:

1. Return a value
2. Throw a value
3. Call `std::abort` or `std::exit` (possibly indirectly)
4. (`std::longjmp` which you shouldn't use)

If you don't do any of the above, then behaviour will be undefined. If you don't want to do 1., then your options are 2. or 3. Abort and exit will terminate the process. A throw can be caught, but an uncaught throw will cause `std::abort`.

Note that just because you don't find a value, it's not necessarily impossible to return some value. What you can do is return a "sentinel" value that represents "not found". For example, `std::string` functions that return an index will return `std::string::npos` when there is no result. Functions returning a pointer might return null, and functions returning an iterator would return an iterator the the end of the range.

If there is no representation of your return type that could be reserved for a sentinel, there is a way to add such representation by wrapping the return type with additional state. The standard library has a generic wrapper for this: `std::optional`.

Another wrapper is the proposed [`std::expected`](https://github.com/viboes/std-make/tree/master/doc/proposal/expected) (it's not accepted to the standard as far as I know, but there are plenty of non-standard implementations). It allows storing information about the reason for not returning a proper value which similar to what you can do with exceptions.

---

P.S. Your function appears to be nearly identical to `std::find_if`. Use standard algorithms when possible. Also consider a data structure that is more efficient for searching if the search space is large.

Comment: pedagogical advice: never work with negative examples. those are most likely to remember =)